# Call remote test library constructor as keyword from Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Is it possible to call Test Library constructor from Robot Framework?
Using Remote library interface (NRobot.Server) to connect from RF to Test Library (implemented in C#).
Currently its exposing all public methods implemented under Test Library except constructors.

There are multiple Test Libraries in our project where some functionality implemented as part of constructors. 
Hence need a way to call constructor as a test step to execute certain functionality whenever required.

If not possible then may need to move functionality from constructors to new public methods. But want to avoid that if possible.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Well, if you use the `Import Library` keyword from your test to import the lib (instead of importing it int the setrings table), the constructor of the lib will be invoked when execution reaches the `Import Library` keyword in your test.

Comment: @BenceKaulics -- Yeah I already noticed that but was just exploring if there was a way to call constructor directly. Thanks anyways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - no.
When calling a remote library, you're actually just the client in an XML-RPC comm protocol; it is the server's responsibility to have the library instantiated, so it (the very same library) can process your instructions and act as needed. Thus normally the library is already instantiated when you call it from your RF code - too late to invoke its constructor.

Naturally, this can be implemented differently - for the remote library server to instantiate the target library on a (special) call, and thus you'll to be able to provide constructor arguments, but that is library design/code change required in it.

---

This is in contrast of using local libraries, where they are instantiated in your local interpreter, on their import.